# Git hook and wordpress git pull page not found

Tags: php, wordpress, git, githooks, bitbucket-server

So I was searching and can't find how to set up git hook with wordpress

I added a deploy.php to my public_html directory where is my wordpress blog!

so when I commit to git stuff, something server doesn't pull it and when I type www.example/depoly.php

it shows error 404 page not found its there any way to make wordpress avoid that file and just execute content:`<pre>
<?php system("git pull");?>
</pre>`

ANY HELP THANKS:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [git](/questions/tagged/git) `post-receive` hooks to trigger automated deployment. The `post-receive` hook will automatically will automatically be triggered by Git.

As an example - In `hooks/post-receive` put the following

```
GIT_REPO=$HOME/myrepo.git
PUBLIC_WWW=/var/www/myrepo

cp $GIT_REPO $PUBLIC_WWW
```

If you require further detailed documentation - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

An example of automated deployment on website - http://www.sitepoint.com/one-click-app-deployment-server-side-git-hooks/

Comment: Hi, Stash developer here. Just wanted to point out that if this hook is going in Stash that you need to put the hook in the hooks/post-receive.d instead, as we hijack the post-receive file to detect when a push is complete.

You could also write the plugin as a Repository Hook plugin if you wanted to as well.

Comment: Aha, that's great to know. Thanks.